# emscripten - string/char* parameter reference weirdness

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten

So I'm playing around with emscripten and making linked lists.  I started with the following code in C -

```
struct Node {
  struct Node *next;
  char *value;
};

extern struct Node *ll_new_node(char *value) {
    struct Node *node;
    node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->value = value;
    return node;
}

extern struct Node *ll_add(struct Node *root, char *value) {
  struct Node *node = ll_new_node(value);
  if (root == NULL) {
    root = node;
  } else {
    tail(root)->next = node;
  }
  return root;
}

//....
```

In the page I'm calling the code this way -

```
var new_node = Module.cwrap('ll_new_node', 'object', ['string'])
var add = Module.cwrap('ll_add', 'object', ['object', 'string']);
var list = 0;
Zepto(function($){
  var printList = function() {
    var node = list;
    var s = "head -> ";
    while (node != null && node != 0) {
      s = s + value(node) + " -> ";
      node = next(node);
    }
    s = s + "NULL";
    $('#display').text(s);
  };
  printList();
  $('#addBtn').on('click', function() {
    var add_value = $('#itemField').val();
    if (add_value && add_value.length > 0) {
      list = add(list, add_value);
      printList();
    }
  });
  //...
});
```

What was happening was if I put "A" in the text box and added it to the list, "head -> A -> NULL" would print. Then if I but "B" in the text box and added it to the list, "head -> B -> B -> NULL" would print. The same pattern continued as more nodes were added. It was adding the new node, but it seems all `node->value` fields pointed to a shared string reference.

I made some test code in C to build and print a list, and it worked as expected with no changes. I ended up fixing it via emscripten by using `strcpy` on the string passed into `ll_new_node` and assigning the copy to `node->value`.

Is this "expected behavior" or a bug?  Is the "copied reference" to the string due to some problem with how I'm using it on the JavaScript side? Is there some way to tell Emscripten not to do this?

Comment: What are you including for the implementation of malloc? I hear including dlmalloc.c is advised. Check out [https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/41]

Comment: @JasonRice I'm just using `malloc` from `stdlib.h` - I'll give `dlmalloc` a try and see if this issue is fixed.